# How secure is Angular?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I've been comparing the Angular approach (single page app) with the traditional JSP and
I'm still not see how an Angular app can be safe. In particular, I think the session and
transaction continuity are now moved to the unsecured realm of the browser (or other user agent)
instead of living in the more secured backend realm.

Since the session can be easily stealed from a browser, I'm concerned that the whole security
can be thrown out the window by the use of a Single Page Application.

Am I to off in my understanding?

This is how I can see both models (JSP versus Angular):

```
Old Model (JSP)                  New Model (Angular)


* UI                             * UI
                                 * session
                                 * tx continuity/controller

1. browser (insecure realm)      3. browser (insecure realm)
---------------------------      ---------------------------
2. backend (secure realm)        4. backend (secure realm)

* session                        * API
* tx continuity/controller       * primitive operations
* primitive operations           * database
* database
```

If a hacker compromises #3 it can be catastrophic since the user agent (probably not a browser anymore) will be able to call all the primitives and wreak havoc in the database.

If a hacker compromises #1 it won't be catastrophic since the controller is still validating all transactions in the backend.

Comment: The backend still handles and validates user input, even in SPAs.

Comment: Let's say the "Delete" button was activated because of an expensive set of conditions while displaying it in the UI, If the user clicks on it, the backend will need to validate all those conditions for a second time before actually executing it (to make sure it was a valid option)?

Comment: Yes access control validation should also always be done in `DELETE` requests. You don't need a webbrowser/webapplication to send a webrequest. That's nothing to do with angular (or any kind of frontend)

Comment: The only thing I can understand from your question is "what if someone gets a link sent through email and decides to just click it" or perhaps too "what if someone visits a totally unrelated website, clicks a button, but this is actually a disguise for a `<form action="//my-ng-site.com" method="POST">` with a submit button... That's called XSRF, and [angular has modules](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule) out of the box to counter this ([see also](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe))

Comment: @Pieterjan Great, I need to make sure all actions are fully authorized in in every call. About the XSRF, well it may have been Angular in the first call, but the hacker now replaced it by a different user agent.

Comment: you would need to provide a working example and show exactly what you did to "hack" the app, in order to prove or disprove your theory.

Comment: In JSP the session is cookie dependant, so you can also have session hijacking (just copy the cookie). Whatever you use, in web development you must NEVER relly on browser's security. The back end is responsible for security.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an equally secure approach with both Angular and JSP. To achieve this, the Angular app uses a backend for frontend (BFF), which provides an application level cookie layer. That is, you need backend components to support the SPA.

See [this best practices doc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff-pr) for the moving parts. The SPA can use an API driven approach to get OAuth request URLs and to forward client secrets to the authorization server.

It is tricky, but the usual motivation with SPAs is to enable productive and modern frontend focused development, while the BFF assists the SPA to provide website equivalent security.

Comment: I tend to think that cookies are more heavily protected in the browsers, while the Angular session id is just a variable that the browser doesn't treat in any particular way (for good ro bad).